# Best way to ingest pd.DataFrame to SQL database with violating UniqueConstraint /w SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to ingest data from a pd.DataFrame into a sql database using SqlAlchemy. The data contains some rows that are still in the database which yields to a UniqueViolation Error. My actual running version of that problem has too loop over the rows and commits every line.

```
data = pd.read_json('data_to_ingest_into_db.JSON')
for _, row in data.iterrows():
    try:
        session.add(generate_obs_data_object(row_dict))
        session.commit()
    except (
            exc.IntegrityError, errors.UniqueViolation,
            exc.DataError) as e:
        session.rollback()
        continue
```

I am sure that this solution is not the best way to deal with that kind of problem. I think something like bulk_insert and replace would fix it but SqlAlchemy does not provide such a functionality.

Comment: you could load into a staging table then merge new rows ?

Comment: @Datanovice do you mean to get the whole table from the db to treat this as a staging table? The table has several millions of rows.

Comment: no to treat your dataframe as a staging table, you load this into a temp/staging table then handle the logic within SQL, i.e only load in the delta and replace unique rows with the newer delta.